# parabola locus problem

Tags: conic-sections

If $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ be the angle made by tangents to the axis of $y^2=4x$ from point $P$ and if $Q_1+Q_2=45^{\circ}$ then locus of $P$ is
[for options see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/womuZ.png)

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2600622/how-to-find-the-angle-between-the-two-tangents-on-a-parabola

Comment: Please make your questions self-contained instead of making the people you’re asking for help go chasing links that can go stale.

Comment: @amd the link which I added is just additional information which is not at all necessary for solving the problem.... nevertheless I will take care next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P(X,Y)$ be the pole.

The equation of polar or equivalently the chord:

$$Yy-2(x+X)=0 \tag{1}$$

Substitute $x=\dfrac{y^2}{4}$ into $(1)$,

\begin{align}
  y^2-2Yy+2X &= 0 \\
  y_1+y_2 &= 2Y \\
  y_1 y_2 &= 4X \\
  m_1 &= \frac{2}{y_1}  \tag{$2yy'=4$} \\
  m_2 &= \frac{2}{y_2}  \\
  \frac{m_1+m_2}{1-m_1 m_2} &= \frac{2(y_1+y_2)}{y_1 y_2-4} \\
 \tan 45^{\circ} &= \frac{4Y}{4X-4} \\
 Y &= X-1
\end{align}